# Spring JPA and LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring-jpa. I have 2 tests.

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void testFindAll() {
    List<Engine> eList = engineService.findAll();
    Engine e = eList.get(0); //this engine id=3
    List<Translation> tList = e.getTranslations();
    for(Translation t : tList) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This method fails with this exception:

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
>   a collection of role: xxx.Engine.translations, could not initialize
>   proxy - no Session

However, this method works just fine:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void testFindOne() {
    Engine e = engineService.findOne(3);
    List<Translation> tList = e.getTranslations();
    for(Translation t : tList) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Why translation list is successfully loaded in one case, but not in another?

EDIT: service/repo code:

```
public interface EngineRepository extends JpaRepository<Engine, Integer>
{   
}
```

.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class EngineService
{
    @Autowired
    private EngineRepository engineRepository;

    public List<Engine> findAll()
    {
        return engineRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Engine findOne(Integer engId)
    {
        return engineRepository.findOne(engId);
    }
}
```

.

```
public class Engine implements Serializable {
    ...
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="ID", referencedColumnName="TRAN_ID",  insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable=true)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
    private List<Translation> translations;
    ...
}
```

Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"xxx.dao"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"xxx.dao", "xxx.service", "xxx.bean"})
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class SpringDataConfig {

  @Autowired
  private Environment environment;

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("db.url"));
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("db.driverClass"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("db.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("db.password"));
    return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws NamingException {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);

    Properties properties = new Properties();


    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getProperty("hibernate.showSQL"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getProperty("hibernate.formatSQL"));

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("xxx.model");
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateJpaVendorAdapter);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(properties);

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
  }

  @Bean
  public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);

    return transactionManager;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of `engineService.findAll()` and `engineService.findOne()`?

Comment: It just wraps engineRepository methods

Comment: Also add the definition of the engine entity.and the jpa configuration.

Comment: findAll() is returning a collection of detached entities. Then when trying to loop through those entities and access lazy initialized collections,

Comment: @Yogendra Sharma what should I do to fix that?

Comment: @bigGuy may be You error means, that your code, which tries to get element from collection, working outside from Hibernate session. Session was closed some time before so you get lazy detached collection.

Comment: or just try to use @OnetoMany f etch=FetchType.Eggar

Comment: eager gives different exception: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: collection is not associated with any session; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that the session gets closed after the first line in the first case. You should check out the JpaRepository implementation of findAll().

Answer (score 0):

### Integration Testing with Spring

It seems you're failing to provide a Spring Context within your TestCase, what that means? The `@Transactional` is being ignored. Therefore you end up with the closed session exception, because there is no transaction.

Take a look how to configure a TestCase with a Spring Context [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management)

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
// ApplicationContext will be loaded from AppConfig and TestConfig
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AppConfig.class, TestConfig.class})
public class MyTest {

     @Autowired
     EngineService engineService;

     @Test
     @Transactional
     public void testFindOne() {}

     @Test
     @Transactional
     public void testFindAll() {}

}
```

Comment: I have @ContextConfiguration in my tests class

Comment: TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive() does output true within the test method?

Comment: So you have a problem with your TestCase configuration and Spring, check the linked documentation. Would be helpful if you posted a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example or at least the full TestCase

Comment: Here is a [example of a correct configuration](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/src/test/java/com/mycompany/myapp/service/UserServiceTest.java)